# I can't access apple.com from my Macbook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, websites, apple-store

For some reason I cannot access apple.com from my MacBook since last week. Was Lion at that time, so I thought updating to Mountain might help, but no luck. Also a full reset and back to original settings of my router didn't help.
Funny thing is though, my iPhone and iPad can go to apple.com via Wifi and the Macbook will as well when it is connected by LAN cable. Just not via Wifi. Also iTunes can only reach the Apple Store via cable, not wifi. The iOs devices have again no problem.

Somebody??

Comment: Have you tried different browsers on your Mac? Have you tried making a new user and logging into it?

Comment: `Also iTunes can only reach the Apple Store via cable, not wifi`: Shouldn't we conclude from this that it is a WiFi configuration problem on your MacBook? Have you tried reconfiguring it (retyping the password, checking security type) in System Preferences>Network?

Answer (score 2):

I would run `/System/Library/CoreServices/Network Diagnostics.app` and isolate what isn't working on the Mac.

It's hard to guess based on the information you have edited into the question.